# Show that entropy and average code length depend only on source code, probability and alphabet

Tags: coding-theory, entropy

I have an exercise to show that the entropy and the average code length depend only on the source code with the probability and the alphabet, but I don't have an idea how to start.

If we observe the formulas for both of them, we will notice that the requirements are source code and probability, but is this a start?

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track. Pick two sources with two different source alphabets, but have the same distribution defined on them. So, assuming they are discrete sources, the distributions are the same vectors with different labels. Then, you just need to show that when you compute the entropy and the expected code length for the same source coding scheme and output alphabet, you end up with the same result for the two sources.

Comment: @curlycharcoal I got it. Thanks for the idea.